# Index of nth occurrence of a character in a given string in UNIX

Tags: shell, unix, ksh

consider the string

```
s=pqrPQR456PQRpqr
```

Now

```
expr index $s p
```

gives me ans as 1

But how to find index of p which is after R or index of any repetitive character; that is what I'm  unable to get.

Comment: perl -e '$_="pqrPQR456PQRpqr"; while(/p/g) { print pos()." "; }'

Comment: please let us know which shell you are using. `#!/bin/sh or #!/bin/bash or #!/bin/ksh or ...`? Tags would be `bash or sh or ksh or ..`. In any case, doing this just in shell is strictly an academic exercise. Learn about awk at a minimum or perl, python, or many others. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

You can get substrings based on the index.

```
$ s=pqrPQR456PQRpqr
$ n=$(expr index $s p)
$ echo "${s:$n}"
qrPQR456PQRpqr
```

This at least gives you the string which follows the character you were searching for.

Answer (score 0):

---

```
#!/bin/ksh
ind=`expr index string substring`
count_occ=`echo "$string"|tr -cd $substring|wc -c`
count=1
echo " The $substring occurs at : $ind "
while [ $count -lt $count_ind ]
do
     rem_str=${string:$ind}
     new_ind=`expr index $rem_str $substring`
     count=`expr $count + 1`
     ind=`expr $ind + $new_ind`
     echo "$ind"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that will give a single character offset without calling an external program like `expr`.  It counts positions from zero rather than one (zero is more commonly used for the first character position).

```
# Take two parameters:
# $1 - the string
# $2 - target character
# $3 - the offset, default is 0
function strchr {
   typeset -i offset
   string="$1"
   target="$2"
   offset="$3"
   (( $# < 3 )) && offset=0

   while (( $offset < ${#string} ))
   do
       char=${string:$offset:1}
       [[ $char == $target ]] && break;
       (( offset++ ))
   done
   echo "$offset"
}

s='pqrPQR456PQRpqr'
i=$(strchr "$s" 'p')
echo "i: $i"
j=$(strchr "$s" 'p' $(( $i + 1 )) )
echo "j: $j"
```

Gives:

```
i: 0
j: 12
```